# Manifest validation error in MSIX WinForms package

Tags: winforms, msix

I have created a C# WinForms DotNet 6.0 app that I have packaged using a Visual Studio 2022  MSIX app packaging project. I have followed these instructions: [MSIX packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net). When I sideload the app package, I get the following error message:

> Manifest validation error: Line 20, Column 27, Reason: The file name "MT\MT.exe" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']" doesn't exist in the package.<

However, folder and file both exist in the 'Release' folder. In any case, file and folder locations have been automatically generated from the .appxmanifest.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong? Many thanks!